# Filtering files with names starting with a specific string

Tags: r, regex

My folder contains 4 files

```
!AR01_061.TXT
AR01_060.TXT
AR01_061.TXT
AR01_062.TXT
```

The goal is to filter to get a list of 3 files
I use this fragment

```
Duzy.rej <- dir_ls(paste0(sciezka, "/Duzy rejestrator/"), regexp = "(AR01_.)(.*\\.TXT$)")
print (Duzy.rej)
```

Result

```
> print (Duzy.rej)
K:/Inne/WM/Duzy rejestrator/AR01_061.TXT
K:/Inne/WM/Duzy rejestrator/!AR01_061.TXT
K:/Inne/WM/Duzy rejestrator/AR01_062.TXT
K:/Inne/WM/Duzy rejestrator/AR01_060.TXT
```

When I modify the regular expression, the effect is far from expected

```
Duzy.rej <- dir_ls(paste0(sciezka, "/Duzy rejestrator/"), regexp = "^(AR01_.)(.*\\.TXT$)")
print (Duzy.rej)
```

```
> print (Duzy.rej)
character(0)
```

I don't understand why "^" doesn't eliminate names other than those starting with "AR01_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `regexp` is passed to `grep` with all the results found so far. So, you end up with full paths, not just filenames that `grep` has to handle.

Thus, you need to use

```r
dir_ls(paste0(sciezka, "/Duzy rejestrator/"), regexp = "(^|/)AR01_[^/]+\\.TXT$")
```

*Details*:

- `(^|/)` - start of string or `/`
- `AR01_` - a literal string
- `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than the `/` char (folder separator char)
- `\.TXT` - `.TXT` text
- `$` - end of string.